# How do I pass a string to the page I'm navigating to?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of image paths. I also have 7 IconButtons which when clicked opens a page which shows the images in the list. How do I pass the image path when navigating to the page?

#### Image List

```dart
final List<String> imgList = [
  'Assets/ban0.jpg',
  'Assets/ban1.jpg',
  'Assets/ban3.jpg',
  'Assets/ban4.jpg',
  'Assets/ban5.jpg',
  'Assets/ban6.jpg',
];
```

#### IconButton

```dart
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.image_search),
  color: Colors.teal,
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => QuestionsImages(),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

#### PhotoView in the new page

```dart
PhotoView(
  enableRotation: true,
  imageProvider: AssetImage(''),
),
```

Comment: Would this help? https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Answer (score 1):

```
class SecondScreen {
  final String imgPath;

  ScreenArguments(this.imgPath);
}

class FirstScreen{
 /*
your code
*/
 onPressed: () {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => SecondScreen('Assets/ban0.jpg'),
      ),
    );
  },
}
```

in this way you can pass string arguments. without hardcoding the string, you can pass an array element too!

Answer (score 0):

Arguments in flutter are passed across screens via constructors.
In the second screen class, accept arguments of type string as follows:

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
   final String URL;
   const SecondScreen({Key key, this.url}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
         body: Image.asset(url),
      );
  }
}
```

To pass the parameter from the first class:

```
class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    final List<String> imgList = [
       'Assets/ban0.jpg',
       'Assets/ban1.jpg',
       'Assets/ban3.jpg',
       'Assets/ban4.jpg',
       'Assets/ban5.jpg',
       'Assets/ban6.jpg',
    ];

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
             title: Text("Title"),
          ),

          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                 Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => SecondScreen(
                            url: imgList[0],
                        ),
                    ),
                );
             },
             child: Icon(Icons.add),
         ), 
     );
   }
}
```